# How does the Subterfuge toolkit bypass SSL?

Tags: tls

As the title says, does anybody know how Subterfuge bypasses the SSL layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Subterfuge](https://code.google.com/p/subterfuge/) is a Man-In-The-Middle tool kit that allows you to intercept communication on a LAN. Generally this is done by ARP Poisoning, tricking the client into thinking your IP is the destination. From there the attacker could steal credentials, inject malicious code, or change data.

The tool does incorporate [sslstrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/), which is a tool that replaces all `https://` instances in a website with `http://`. This would bypass SSL from the client to the attacker, and then relay the data to the destination server via SSL.

```
Client ->[plaintext]-> MITM ->[SSL]-> Destination
```

This only works if the original webpage was using `http://` and then linked to `https://` either via a hyperlink or a form. If the client tries to make a direct connection to the server using SSL (i.e: from bookmark), then you would not be able to force them into plaintext.